# How can I change some elements in dataset by related column and row

Tags: dataset

```
dataset={<|"type"->"row_1","A"->1.338275`*^6,"B"->0.|>,<|"type"->"row_2","A"->1.318498`*^6,"B"->1.1498`*^6|>,<|"type"->"row_3","A"->38084.`,"B"->35557.`|>,
<|"type"->"row_5","A"->181796.`,"B"->0.`|>,<|"type"->"row_4","A"->471946.`,"B"->449778.`|>,
<|"type"->"row_2","A"->1.516415`*^6,"B"->1.266298`*^6|>,<|"type"->"row_3","A"->44514.`,"B"->44398.`|>,
<|"type"->"row_1","A"->1.346733`*^6,"B"->1.16753`*^6|>,<|"type"->"row_4","A"->533791.`,"B"->492312.`|>,<|"type"->"row_5","A"->228284.`,"B"->0.`|>}//Dataset
```

I want to replace 0. value in [row_5,B] become value of [row_5,A], and the value is changing in many rows, and I don't like to type it {0.0->1.516*10^6}

One solution of mine is

```
1.select row_5 lines, and split the data in parts 2=part1,part2, 
2.change part1[with row_5] modifiy row B by rowA
3.combine part1 and part2
```

and I do this in the association, not the dataset.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Like this?  `ReplacePart[dataset, {{2, "a"}, {5, "a"}} -> y]`

Comment: @JasonB yes, may be values of y is y1, y2, also some ways like Query, dataset[All, something] is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change all rows of type "row_5" to that the "B" value is replaced with the corresponding "A" value, we can write:

```
dataset[All, <| #, "B" -> Replace[#type, {"row_5" -> #A, _ -> #B}] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

If we only want to change the cases where the "B" value is zero, we can add that as an extra condition:

```
dataset[All, <| #, "B" -> Replace[#type, {"row_5" :> #A /; #B == 0., _ -> #B}] |>&]
```

If we wanted to replace all zero values in the B column with the corresponding A value, we could do this:

```
dataset[All, <| #, "B" -> Replace[#B, 0. -> #A] |> &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Hi, yes, but sometimes, it's not 0. but 1.15*10^100, and maybe not so easy to type it rightly, since the table is large,some rows are hidden, and If some 0.0 is not in type=row_5, I don't want it to be replaced.

Comment: So you want to change all row_5 entries, even when the value is not zero?

Comment: yes, that's the real purpose, better if could do a check, if value of [row_5,B] is 0, then replaced by [row_5,A]

Comment: ha, I find it , thanks.
`dataset[All,<|#,"B"->If[#type=="row_5",#A,#B]|>&]`

Answer (score 2):

Probably more than one way to do this, but scrolling through the documentation I found this,

> `dataset[All,{n->f}]` selectively maps $f$ onto the $n^{th}$ column

What you want to do is map a [`replacement rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) on to the "a" column,

```
dataset[All, {"a" -> (# /. {2 -> y1, 5 -> y2} &)}]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, I changed the dataset and make the problem clearer

Comment: Anyway, thanks, I find the answer, via WReach's answer.